# separating decimal numbers with commas in asp.net eg:1,23,456

Tags: asp.net, formatting

I tried this format, got output as `1,234,567,890.00`

but I need  in this format

```
1,23,567   
decimal unitPrice = 1234567890.00m; 
TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(unitPrice).ToString("##,#0.00");
```

Comment: Need help asap !  thanks in advance !

Comment: you are already getting comma separated decimal number!! what is you need?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can do this by creating a custom number format info for your needs...example is here for your reference -

```
    int yourNumber = 111234;
    NumberFormatInfo nfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
    nfo.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ",";
    nfo.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] { 3, 2 };
    string str = yourNumber.ToString("N0", nfo);

    Response.Write("answer is : " + str);
```

Comment: The Pleasure is completely mine!